# Vue directive - execute ajax call after url is entered bu the user

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom vue directive that is supposed to make an ajax call after that the user has inserted an url into an input field. I have the problem that the `fetch()` function I've included into the directive will not be executed when the url is entered.

This is the code that I have in my template:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
 <input type="search" v-model="url">
 <iframe :v-xframe="url"></iframe>
</div>
</template>
```

and this is the code in my directive file

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const xframe = {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        let url = binding.value;
        if( url && url.startsWith('https://www') ) {
            fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${url}`)
            .then( (res) => res.text() )
            .then( (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                let iframeContent = data.replace(/<head([^>]*)>/i, `<head$1>
                    <base href="${url}">
                        <script>
                        // X-Frame-Bypass navigation event handlers
                        document.addEventListener('click', e => {
                            if (frameElement && document.activeElement && document.activeElement.href) {
                                e.preventDefault()                                
                                frameElement.load(document.activeElement.href)
                            }
                        });
                        document.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                            if (frameElement && document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form && document.activeElement.form.action) {
                                e.preventDefault()
                                if (document.activeElement.form.method === 'post') {
                                    frameElement.load(document.activeElement.form.action, {method: 'post', body: new FormData(document.activeElement.form)});
                                }else{
                                    frameElement.load(document.activeElement.form.action + '?' + new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.activeElement.form)));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        </\script>`);
                el.srcdoc = iframeContent;
            });
        }
    }         
}
```

Is there any solution I can implement to let the fetch function begin executed after that an url is available?

Comment: why do you bind your directive? `:v-xframe="url"`

Comment: because the url as you can see from the code, is inserted from the user with an input element and it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `bind(el, binding, vnode)` function that called once when directive bound to element, you would use `update(el, binding, vnode)` function for this purpose, you can read more about it in vue doc : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions

Comment: in update function, did you console.log(url) before `fetch` to see its print url or not? did you try axios?

Comment: the url will be added to the directive value but will not be logged into the console. I didn't use axios because I don't want any dependency for this simple directive.